# problem while converting object into datetime in c#

Tags: c#, exception, datetime

I am getting string value in object let say "28/05/2010". While i am converting it in to DateTime it is throwing exception as :

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The Code is:

```
object obj = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q17]).Value2;
Type type = obj.GetType();
string strDate3 = string.Empty;
double dbl = 0.0;

if (type == typeof(System.Double))
{
    dbl = Convert.ToDouble(((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q17]).Value2);
    strDate3 = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl).ToShortDateString();
}
else
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime().Date;
    //////////dt = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(obj));
    **dt = Convert.ToDateTime(obj).Date;**
    strDate3 = dt.ToShortDateString(); 
}
```

The double star "**" line gets exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your exception is that you have different culture set up for sql server and your application. So, you are getting the string from the database as "dd/MM/yyyy" and in your application this value is parsed as "MM/dd/yyyy". The 28 is invalid month, so it throws an exception. Use  `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy",           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` to get the right value, or use the same culture.

UPDATE: You can check windows settings from Control Panel -> Region and Language. For the sql server culture settings and how you can define culture for your application here is a good explanation http://alainrivas.blogspot.com/2008/09/aspnet-and-sql-server-globalization.html

Comment: I think you are right.Ok thanks sir, but how can i set this??

Comment: Thanks I tried this , it was working. But To change the server's settings is not the proper way. So I just thought , . I insert in web.config as  <globalization culture="en-GB"/> as ur URL sugessted. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the format string as dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: +1 I think that was the OP's original intention as that line has been commented out, all that is missing really is the format provider.

Comment: Add the revised code and the new error in the question please.