# Error while converting string to DateTime after publishing to web server

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using below code

```
    DateTime dtt=new DateTime();
    dtt = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);


  //  DateTime dtt = DateTime.Parse(FromDate); //this also gives the same error

    con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 1; i <= TotalDays; i++)
    {         
        string updateHotelBooking = "Update tbl_hotelbookingdetail set `BookedRoom`=`BookedRoom`+"+1+", `AvailableRoom`=`TotalRoom`-`BookedRoom` where `HotelID`="+HotelID+" AND `CurrentDate`='"+dtt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+"'";
        MySqlCommand cmd7=new MySqlCommand(updateHotelBooking,con);
        cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        dtt = dtt.AddDays(1);
    }
```

This code is in one of my webservice which I am using for iPhone application.

here `FromDate` is string with value in this formate `15-11-2011` which is coming from the application in string format. I am converting it to DateTime because in loop of total days
`I need to add day to dtt.`

It is working fine on local host with dtt value `15-11-2011 00:00:00`

but when I published it,it gives error

`String was not recognize as valid DateTime`

Comment: this may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903339/problem-while-converting-object-into-datetime-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your server uses a different culture by default - and your code is just using the current thread culture.

You *can* specify this using [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) - or specify the pattern explicitly with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) - but we need to know more about where the string is coming from to suggest the best approach. Is it from the user? If so, you should use the user's culture to parse it. Is it a specific format (e.g. from an XML document) instead? If so, parse using that specific format.

Ideally, get rid of the string part entirely - if you're fetching it from a database for example, can you store it and fetch it *as* a `DateTime` instead of as a string? It's worth trying to reduce the number of string conversions involved as far as possible.

EDIT: To parse from a fixed format of dd-MM-yyyy I would use:

```
DateTime value;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd-MM-yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,
                           out value))
{
     // Value will now be midnight UTC on the given date
}
else
{
    // Parsing failed - invalid data
}
```

Comment: Updated my question as per you ask from where the string is coming.and it will be in fix format of 'dd-MM-yyyy' as per it will be string

Answer (score 2):

What are you culture settings on your local machine and on the server?

The DateTime conversion is dependent on the current culture - dates are written quite differently in different countries.

One way to make the conversion "predictible" is to use the invariant culture:

```
DateTime dtt = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

the server date format may be in mm/dd/yyyy and you are trying to pass dd/mm/yyyy

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] dateValues = { "30-12-2011", "12-30-2011", 
                              "30-12-11", "12-30-11" };
      string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";
      DateTime parsedDate;

      foreach (var dateValue in dateValues) {
         if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.", 
                              dateValue, parsedDate);
         else
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.", 
                              dateValue);
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    Unable to convert '30-12-2011' to a date and time.
//    Unable to convert '12-30-2011' to a date and time.
//    Unable to convert '30-12-11' to a date and time.
//    Converted '12-30-11' to 12/30/2011.
```

[Check this for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Log (or otherwise provide feedback to yourself) what FromDate is.  Maybe it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

May the Language Settings on the Server are different so it does not recognize the `dd-MM-yyyy` - try using `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`